# do I have to declare the $http service when requiring other services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module("ABC.services").service("configService", [
  'loggerService', function(logger, $http) {
    debugger;
    return this.get = function(onError, onSuccess) {
      return $http.get("/api/config/").success(function(config) {
        logger.debug('loaded config');
        return onSuccess(config);
      }).error(onError);
    };
  }
]);
```

(I have a logger that's more complex than `$log`)

I find that at the debugger line `$http` is undefined unless I include '$http' in the list of dependencies. The [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) don't discuss this use case. Their example of native service injection looks like:

`angular.module('myModule', [], function($provide) {`

Would I be required to declare `$provide` as a dependency if I was also using one of my own services? I'm just really confused about when I can rely on the automatic injection of `$` services and when I have to explicitly declare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only inject the modules when you use it. If you don't use it in the code, you don't have to inject. (In the example you referred, because the code uses the `$provide`, that is why it is injected.)

When you use *array notation* to inject the modules, you need the modules declared in the array to match the parameters in the function. For example:

```
angular.module("ABC.services").service("configService", [
  'loggerService', '$http', function(logger, $http) {
```

or without using array notation

```
angular.module("ABC.services").service("configService", function(loggerService, $http) { ...
```

And the advantage of using array notation is it protects against minification.

Comment: I don't feel that this answers my question -- I knew all of those things already. Why can't I rely on the automatic injection in the case of services that are native to angular?

Comment: @jcollum What is automatic injection? I haven't heard about it. Show me the link to the doc please. You don't have to use array notation if you don't like, just inject the modules directly to the function.

Comment: @jcollum In your example you are using the array notation, so AngularJS is expecting the same number of arguments in the array; you can't go "halfway". Either you use it as described by sza or don't use it at all (showed in the example too).

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga I linked to an angular doc that shows injection without anything in the array. The docs are unclear on why you can rely on automatic injection ($provide) but when you use explicit injection (logger, $http) you can't rely on angular to automatically inject the $http service.

Comment: @jcollum it's no secret AngularJS docs can be done in a better way. That being said, the concept you are referring to is [Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), which is greatly described... in the proper link.